# Add a new column with the list of values from all rows meeting a criterion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I have some list of data in the form of:**

```
        date           value
'2017-01-01 01:01:01'   99
'2017-01-02 01:01:01'   98
'2017-01-03 01:01:01'   97
....
'2017-01-30 01:01:01'   95
'2017-01-31 01:01:01'   94
```

**I would like to add a column such that it is like:**

```
        date          value     list
 ...
 ...
 ...
'2017-01-30 01:01:01'   95  [99,98,97,95]
'2017-01-31 01:01:01'   94  [99,98,97,95,94]
```

*Where the third column is a list of the values in the second column if the date falls within a certain time frame (say 5 days) prior to the date in the corresponding row.*

Comment: You're getting downvoted because your question is completely vague.

Comment: Just click the (?) help icon in the top right of the question text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-01-01 01:01:01', '2017-01-02 01:01:01', '2017-01-03 01:01:01', '2017-01-30 01:01:01', '2017-01-31 01:01:01'],
                   'value': [99,98,97,95,94]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def get_list(row):

   subset = df[(row['date'] - df['date'] <= pd.to_timedelta('5 days')) & (row['date'] - df['date'] >= pd.to_timedelta('0 days'))]
   return str(subset['value'].tolist())

df['list'] = df.apply(get_list, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
              date  value          list
0 2017-01-01 01:01:01     99          [99]
1 2017-01-02 01:01:01     98      [99, 98]
2 2017-01-03 01:01:01     97  [99, 98, 97]
3 2017-01-30 01:01:01     95          [95]
4 2017-01-31 01:01:01     94      [95, 94]
```

Comment: Thanks Riley! Wouldn't the for loop make the code slow and kind of defeat the purpose of pandas?

Comment: I edited the code so that it's cleaner and avoids using a for loop